# Why a-avatar slides a little bit inside a-menu-item

Tags: vue.js, antd

I'm using Ant Design and Vue to create Web App.

I face a problem that the content of `a-avatar` is a little bit moving to the left side.

This is the screenshot of the problem.

[image]

This is the link to my source code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-antd-template-9hwc4?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is according to source code, ant-menu-item will add a `margin-right` to if the children is an icon

[image]

so a menu with icon like this display correctly and always have a right spacing. but I guess they just did not account Avatar also has an icon and can be inside of menu

[image]

I believe this is a bug, but meanwhile, you can just overwrite it. https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-antd-template-oqeko?file=/src/App.vue:478-517